# Datatable with form on multipage validation issue

Tags: jquery, css, sql-server, ajax, datatables

I have created table using datatable with in each row have td with input or select field.
with having on multiple pages.

The issues is the datatable render 10 row html element at time by default and jquery validation render per page as html.

I need solution to put validation of entire cell of all pagination(pages) using jQuery.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<body>
   <table id="banklist">
   <tr>
     <td>
         <input id="bn_0" name="bd[0][bn]" placeholder="Enter Bank Name" value="testbank" aria-required="true" class="valid" aria-invalid="false">
     </td>
     <td>
         <select id="sts_0" class="sts" name="bd[0][sts]" aria-required="true">
                    <option value="">Select Status</option>
                    <option value="Y" selected="">on</option>
                    <option value="N">off</option>
                </select>
     </td>
   </tr> 
<tr>
  <td> 100 more tr td input select <td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
    </style>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/list_newbank.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#banklist').DataTable({
                        scrollX:        true,
                        scrollCollapse: true,
                    });
     });
```

https://jqueryvalidation.org/
jQuery Validation:

```
$("#banklist").validate({
                    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                        var ele_name = element.attr('name');
                        console.log(ele_name);
                        $('.valid').attr('style','border : 1px solid #c2bfbf !important');
                        if($('input,select').hasClass('error')) {
                            //$('label.error').remove();
                            $('input.error, select.error').attr('style','border : 1px solid red !important');
                            error.appendTo( $('.error[name="'+ele_name+'"]').parent('td'));
                        }
                }
  });
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have one form with various fields i used datatable to represent that fields and applied validation on all using jQuery validation plugin and all data comming from PHP MySQL rather that datatable columns or ajax.  The problem is that when I submit form the validation rule apply to current page only but I need to apply it to all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Look at ajax method. Here as example how I used it for almost the same problem:

```
$('#dt-all-orders').DataTable({
    "ajax": "ajax_files/dt_get_all_orders.php",
    "language": {
        "url": "js/datatables/datatables.lang.ua.txt"
    },
    "initComplete": function () {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    },
    "columnDefs": [
        {width    : "30px", targets: [0]},
        {width    : "120px", targets: [2]},
        {width    : "120px", targets: [3]},
        {width    : "120px", targets: [4]},
        {width    : "120px", targets: [5]},
        {width    : "80px", targets: [6]},
        {className: "text-center", targets: [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
        {className: "td-actions text-center", targets: 6},
    ],
    "aoColumns": [
        null,
        { "bSortable": false },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "bSortable": false }
    ],
    "lengthMenu": [
        [10, 25, 50, 100],
        [10, 25, 50, 100]
    ],
    "stateSave": true,
    "deferRender": true,
    "order": [
        [0, "desc"]
    ],
});
```

But in this case you have to manually create all columns and use php file with sql query.

Comment: And after you could try to use validation

Comment: I have one form with various fields i used datatable to represent that fields and applied validation on all using jQuery validation plugin and all data comming from PHP MySQL rather that datatable columns or ajax. The problem is that when I submit form the validation rule apply to current page only but I need to apply it to all pages.

Jquery validation --
[link]https://jqueryvalidation.org/